# ¿Como retener la Id para una consulta en la clausula WHERE?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy buscando como hacer que cuando el usuario ingrese se recoja el `Id`, para posteriormente utilizar para mostrar solo su información y hacer procesos matemáticos-lógicos.

Primero intenté capturar la `SESSION` de la `Id` con una variable así: `$Id = $_SESSION['Id']`. Para luego en la cláusula `WHERE` pueda hacer la condición así: `WHERE registros.Id = "$Id";` Y me sale lo siguiente:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\TDE\Paginas\Admins\Venta_Tienda.php on line 63

Lo importante es, ¿Cómo poder utilizar esa `$_SESSION['Id']` cuando yo quiera?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la línea 63 de tu documento `Venta_Tienda.php`? Es un error de sintaxis de tu código, el que está fallando.

Comment: Tu problema es que estas asumiendo que la sesion tiene un id por defecto y no es asi. Tienes que recuperarlo de BBDD y asignarlo a la sesion.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El mensaje indica claramente un **error de sintaxis en la línea 63 del código** independientemente de si esté recogiendo bien o no la variable `$Id`, posiblemente no hayas concatenado adecuadamente, lo cual para consultas SQL es por cierto una **mala e insegura práctica**. Si quieres ser un programador correcto, en PHP/MySQL este tipo de manejos se hacen mediante consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ahí tu problema es que te falta un `, o )` en una parte de tu código no terminaste bien la sentencia.
Si no intenta lo siguiente cuando el usuario inicie sesión:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = ID_DEL_USUARIO;
//Aquí las demás variables que uses.
```

Cuando hagas la consulta asignalo.

```
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS REGISTROS WHERE REGISTROS.ID = ' $_SESSION["id"];
```

Si hay errores haz un echo para ver que te sale:

```
echo $sql;
```